# Get rid or hide html tags from textarea in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, textarea

I retrieved a body of a textarea using json but the text appears to come with html tags due to some styles have been previously set.

How would I be able to display these lines of text on a new textarea without these html tags being visible? I don't want to get rid of them completely because I still want to keep the styles for the future use.

Comment: Do you want this text to be editable?

Comment: refer this [link][1] old question


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript

Comment: If jQuery is relevant for you, stripping the HTML becomes trivial.. just store the raw value as hidden input and strip the HTML when showing in textarea. See [this test case](http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/54nHw/2/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape html tags from your incoming string from textarea. By a regular expression like `/<(.|\n)*?>/` you can find opening html tags and with `/<(\/.|\n)*?>/` you can find closing tags.

Here is my example:

#### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />

</head>
<body>
  <textarea id="input">
    <p>This is html</p>
  </textarea>
  <textarea id="output">

  </textarea>
```

#### JavaScript

```
var input = document.getElementById('input'),
    output = document.getElementById('output');
output.value = input.value.replace(/<(.|\n)*?>/, '').replace(/<\/(.|\n)*?>/, '');
```

Live in: [**JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/aderiy/7)

You may want to detect closing tags like `/>` with this regular expression: `/\/(.|\n)*?>/`

Answer (score 1):

```css
textarea{width:100%;min-height:75px}
```

```html
<textarea id="input">
    <p>This is html</p>
    <p>This is html</p>
    <p>This is html</p>
</textarea>

<button onClick="removeTags()">Remove</button>

<textarea id="output"></textarea>

<script>
function removeTags(){
  var input = document.getElementById('input');
  var output = document.getElementById('output');
  output.value = input.value.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
}
removeTags();
</script>
```